# Generating MySQL UPDATE statements containing BLOB image data

Tags: sql, mysql, scripting, blob, dml

I'm trying to write an SQL statement that will generate an SQL script that will update a BLOB field with an IMAGE being selected from the database.

This is what I have:

```
select concat( 'UPDATE `IMAGE` SET THUMBNAIL = ', 
               QUOTE( THUMBNAIL ), 
               ' WHERE ID = ', ID, ';' ) as UPDATE_STATEMENT
  from IMAGE;
```

In the above, THUMBNAIL is a BLOB field containing raw image data. When I run the resulting script I get the following error:

```
ERROR at line 2: Unknown command '\\'.
```

I first tried this without the QUOTE() function, like so:

```
select concat( 'UPDATE `IMAGE` SET THUMBNAIL = \'', 
               THUMBNAIL, 
               '\' WHERE ID = ', ID, ';' ) as UPDATE_STATEMENT
  from IMAGE;
```

Running the resulting script produces this error:

```
ERROR at line 2: Unknown command '\0'.
```

What is the proper function to apply to this BLOB field in the select, so the UPDATE statements will work?

If context is required, I'm looking to migrate thumbnails generated on one server to another server for certain image IDs only. I would use mysqldump, but I don't want to clobber the entire table.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I should mention that i know this is possible as mysqldump can generate SQL INSERT statements that contain BLOB data, but I'm not sure what function is used to escape the data properly.

Comment: Did you take a look at how mysqldump escapes the strings it intendes to insert as BLOB?

Comment: I looked at the C code but I cannot make out what it is doing. If I look at the resulting SQL, there are no functions called on the string during insert. It appears to be just a dump of the blob field with single quotes escaped by blackslashes. I'm working with REPLACE() to see how I can do this on the select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must work with hexadecimal format blob. It looks like this:

```
select concat( 'UPDATE `IMAGE` SET THUMBNAIL = ', 
               0xC9CBBBCCCEB9C8CABCCCCEB9C9CBBB...., 
               ' WHERE ID = ', ID, ';' ) as UPDATE_STATEMENT
  from IMAGE;
```

Or you might find it handy to use the [Openrowset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) command

Comment: What function should I call to get the hex format? Do I need to call another function on this value prior to inserting it into the target?

Comment: Check this out, this must have all the information you need. You now have to try till you reach something that suits you.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: I found the MySQL counterpart to the page you linked: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast

Comment: This worked:

    select concat( 'UPDATE `IMAGE` SET THUMBNAIL = UNHEX( \'',
                   HEX( THUMBNAIL ),
                   '\' ) WHERE ID = ', ID, ';' ) as UPDATE_STATEMENT
      from IMAGE;

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php if (isset($_POST['sub'])) { 
     $tfname=$_FILES['f1']['tmp_name'];
     $name=$_POST['hi']; 
     $cont=file_get_contents($tfname);
     $cont=addslashes($cont); 
     mysql_connect("localhost" ,"root" ,"");
     mysql_select_db("k"); 
     $sqlstt="update test_image set
         id='2',name='$name',image='$cont' where id='2' ";
     if(mysql_query($sqlstt)) 
         echo "updated"; 
     else 
         echo "not";         
 } ?>

 <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     Name:-<input type="text" name="hi" /> 
     select image:-<input type="file" name="f1" required value="select" /> 
     <input type="submit" name="sub" value="update" /> 
 </form>
```

this is worked nice check it out